# bluemix-app-scan tag should be renamed to hcl-appscan

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, retag-request

IBM renamed [app scan](https://cloud.appscan.com/AsoCUI/serviceui/home) (again) "HCL AppScan on Cloud". The [bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluemix) tag should be migrated or renamed to something more appropriate.

Comment: Looks like HCL AppScan is [already a thing](https://www.hcltech.com/software/appscan-standard). Is that related to IBM's product?

Comment: why the down vote? bluemix isn't a thing anymore. It's difficult to find questions related to IBM app scan current branding if you didn't know it was bluemix before? @CodyGray you are correct; [see this](https://newsroom.ibm.com/2018-12-06-HCL-Technologies-to-Acquire-Select-IBM-Software-Products-for-1-8B)

Comment: So...they are the same? The downvote is likely because you haven't really made a compelling case here. The request seems valid, but you have to justify it before we can go making major changes to a fundamental feature like the tagging system. I haven't voted either way, but that's why I haven't pulled the trigger on this yet.

Comment: Yes from the article I just found, sounds like HCL bought app scan from IBM (weird that imb logins still work). "Compelling reason" : seems like a rebrand of product would be sufficient reason to name a tag properly.

Answer (score 1):

This tag was renamed to [ibm-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud), so I'm marking this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

I'm not sure if that's the *best* name, though, as it looks like IBM is not marketing "HCL AppScan" using their company name. So this may need to be reconsidered. Please do so in a new support request so that it can be tracked.